# Cannot resolve method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)'

Tags: android

As i titled it, i got an error where startActivity is not recognized. Here is the code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle("Deal");
builder.setMessage("Hello");
builder.setPositiveButton("Call ME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "528543871"));
        startActivity(callIntent);

    }
});
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Comment: `startActivity()` is a method on `Context` and its subclasses, such as `Activity`. Whatever class you have this code in is not a `Context`. If it is a `Fragment`, use `getActivity().startActivity()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare `startActivity` is a method of the `Fragment` class(es)

Comment: Please post your error that you see in your log window

Comment: It's not a Fragment, i have something like this in the log : No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL }

Comment: @cricket_007: Ah, right. Sorry, short on sleep today.

Comment: @stack Seems like you aren't running that code on a tablet or emulator that does not support calling.

Comment: It seems noone here can help me my issue. It now more +5 hours i'm working on it and unable to find the problem.

Comment: I run this in emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The method `startActivity()` is called on a context. As you are calling the method into `onClick()` which is a method from `OnCLickListener` so the method is unresolved. As I can see in your code that you have passed `mContext` in `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor so you can also use that Context variable to call your `startActivity()` method.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle("Deal");
builder.setMessage("Hello");
builder.setPositiveButton("Call ME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "528543871"));
        mContext.startActivity(callIntent); //Correct this line

    }
});
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

OR

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle("Deal");
builder.setMessage("Hello");
builder.setPositiveButton("Call ME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "528543871"));
        getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);

    }
});
builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Comment: method getActivity() is not recognized too.

Comment: try using `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating a Dialog. You're creating a builder.
Try as follow:

```
AlertDialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
myDialog.setTitle("Deal");
myDialog.setMessage("Hello");
myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Call me", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "528543871"));
        startActivity(callIntent);

    }
})
myDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others in the comments have already pointed out, method `startActivity` needs to be called either explicitly from a context `context.startActivity()` or if you're in an Activity `startActivity()` since the Activity implements `Context` interface. In your case, I think this should fix it (use the `mContext` that you have already):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setTitle("Deal");
builder.setMessage("Hello");
builder.setPositiveButton("Call ME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "528543871"));
    mContext.startActivity(callIntent);

}
});

builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Comment: I tried this one too : mContext.startActivity(callIntent) and it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try `getApplicationContext().startActivity(callIntent)` ?

Comment: Where exactly is this code called? What class is this?

Comment: when i write mContext.startActivity(callIntent), i have something like : Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

Comment: Hmm try to surround it in a try/catch and catch the SecurityException?

Comment: Here is the class: http://pastebin.com/LL0CfDeW . Please DONT POST THE WHOLE CODE OF THE CLASS HERE

Comment: Hm, hardly is this the code that should be in the ArrayAdatper, You have a flaw in your logic. It's not adapter's responsibility to make a Dialog and start the activity, it's to merely show the data in a listview. Can you move this logic elsewhere, say in the Activity/Fragment that contains the aforementioned listview?

Comment: When i click on a row it displays Dialog with informations of a person, and on this Dialog i have a button call where when i click on it, it call someone. What's the problem ?

Comment: Instead of adding onClickListener in adapter, can you do it on listView with names like `listviewView.setOnItemClickListener`? That is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I think i can't do this because the listview is in MainActivity.

Comment: So what? Why is that a problem?